# POS POLE Display- how to scroll contents horizontally?

Tags: c#

In my pos application i want to show the total amount and selected
 items on the pole disply. i have a 2x20 character pole display. i want
 to scroll the item names through second row of pole display and first
 row should remain >unchanged(no scroll).

```
public void print(string Total,String Item)
{ 
    SerialPort sport = new SerialPort(myport, 9600, Parity.None,StopBits.One); 
    sport.Open();
    sport.Write(new byte[] { 0x0C }, 0, 1); 
    sport.Write("Total Amount:"+Total);
    //next line 
    port.Write(new byte[] { 0x0A, 0x0D }, 0, 2); sport.Write(Items); 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    port.Close();
}
```